# Using an array as request headers in PHP

Tags: php

I'm trying to send a GET request to an API using PHP `stream_context_create` and `file_get_contents`.

I need to add API keys to the headers of my request, I'm storing these in an array so I easily edit them later and use them in multiple functions. What is a good way to include these arrays as headers?

In this case the key of the array would be the header keys and the value of the array the value of the header.

Some code to explain the problem

```php
<?php
$api = array(
    "X-Api-Id" => "id",
    "X-Api-Key" => "key",
    "X-Api-Secret" => "secret"
);

$options = array(
    "http" => array(
        "header" => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n", // here I need to add the $api array
        "method" => "GET"
    )
);  
return file_get_contents("example.com", FALSE, stream_context_create($options));
?>
```

Comment: General advice for programming: break the problem down. You know what your array looks like, and you know what the string needs to look like. Ignore the _reason_ you're creating that string and think "how can I turn an array into a string?" Then look around on this site, and on the rest of the web, for thousands of examples of people doing similar things.

Comment: Please share more details. What exactly is not working with the given code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply add the info to the header.

```
<?php
$api = [
    'X-Api-Id' => 'id',
    'X-Api-Key' => 'key',
    'X-Api-Secret' => 'secret',
];
$headerData['Content-type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
$headerData = array_merge($headerData, $api);
array_walk($headerData, static function(&$v, $k) { $v = $k.': '.$v; });

$options = array(
    'http' => [
        'header' => implode("\n", $headerData),
        'method' => 'GET'
    ]
);  
return file_get_contents('example.com', FALSE, stream_context_create($options));
?>
```

Comment: Would I be able to implode my current array into the `header` field

Comment: I've just updated the code to keep your $api array and merge the data with the $headerData array. array_walk prepares the values for the implode function.

Answer (score 0):

To encode the data you can use http_build_query().
To add it to the header options you should be able to do something like:

```
$options = array(
    "http" =>array(
        'method'  => 'POST', // GET in your case(?)
        'header'  => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'content' => http_build_query($api)
    )
);
```